# Chef knife plugin(s) not recognized?

Tags: chef-infra

I have chef-client v11.12.2. I installed the knife-block and knife-playground plugins via Gemfile, and see that they're installed.

```
> bundle install
.....
Using knife-block (0.1.1)
Using knife-playground (0.2.2)
Using knife-spork (1.3.4)
......

> bundle show knife-block
/opt/chef-server/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/knife-block-0.1.1
```

However I get this when I do a knife block list, for example. Same issue for knife pg command. What else am I missing?

```
> knife block list
FATAL: Cannot find sub command for: 'block list'
```

Comment: have you tried `bundle exec knife block list`?

Comment: Yes that recognized the command, but why do I have to do that? Why doesn't "knife block list" simply work?

Comment: As coderanger explained, your `bundle install` created a knife binary that was not the one being used by simple calls to knife.  This is the nature of using bundler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `bundle` command installed by chef-server, but probably using the `knife` from an install of chef-client or chefdk. The simple fix is to add `chef` to the Gemfile too (if it isn't being pulled in as a dependency already), and then `bundle exec knife ...`.

Comment: Yes this is probably what happened. I did not configure the box, but the physical box hosts both the chef-server and the chef-client so the person who installed them did exactly what you posted.